# how can I dispatch customized events to all listening elements

Tags: javascript

sample code:

```
var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
evt.initEvent('myevent',true,true);
ele.dispatchEvent(evt)  //ele is an HTML element
```

but it just dispatch the event to only one element, is there an elegant way to broadcast the event to all the elements which use addEventListener('myevent',...) to register a callback function?

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {}; // keep track of the listeners for each event.

// Register the event listeners
function registerListener(elem, evt, d) {
   if (d.hasOwnProperty(evt)) {
      d[evt].push(elem);
   }
   else {
      d[evt] = [];
   }
}

// Get the listeners and dispatch the event to all them
function dispatchAll(evt, d) {
   var listeners = d[evt],
       elem;

   for (var i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
      elem = listeners[i];
      elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
   }
}
```

Comment: uh.. i have thought about this, just want a better solution

Comment: u need Observer Pattern. 
Read ch.7 of *“JavaScript Patterns, by Stoyan Stefanov
(O’Reilly). Copyright 2010 Yahoo!, Inc., 9780596806750.”*